# Img click() after img id change

Tags: jquery

Sorry for my english.

I have a table with the favorites column that contains an image: fav_on or fav_off and its id is fav_on or fav_off.

When I click I change the id (if I check the DOM with firefox the id change correctly), but if I click again, the event connected to the old id runs.

Can someone help me?

thank you

```
<table>
    <tr id="1">
       <td id="fav_ali" data-fav_ico="0"><img src="img/tmp.png" id="fav_off" class="img_btn" title="add to fav"/></td>
       <td id="des_ali" class="cg_ott">aaaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2"> 
       <td id="fav_ali" data-fav_ico="1"><img src="img/tmp.png" id="fav_on" class="img_btn" title="del from fav"/></td>
       <td id="des_ali" class="cg_na">aaaaa</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

```js
$('#fav_off').on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Fav Off click");
  //change DB...
  this.id = "fav_on";
});

$('#fav_on').on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Fav On click");
  //change DB...
  this.id = "fav_off";
});
```

Comment: Don't use an ID. That's not what it's for. You should use a class for this. In addition you can't have multiples of an ID on a page. `fav_ali` and `des_ali` should also be classes. Thirdly an ID can't start with a number. You need to modify the ID of your table rows so they start with a letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly don't amend `id` attributes at runtime as they are meant to be static. Use classes instead.

Secondly, the reason your code doesn't work as you expect is because you attach the event handlers on load. The changing `id` has no bearing on the event handlers that are already on the element. To do what you require, use a delegated event handler. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.fav_off, .fav_on', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('fav_off')) {
    console.log('Fav Off click');
  } else {
    console.log('Fav On click');
  }

  $(this).toggleClass('fav_off fav_on');
  //change DB...
});
```

```css
.fav_on {
  border: 1px solid #c00; /* just to make the effect more obvious */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td id="fav_ali" data-fav_ico="0">
      <img src="img/tmp.png" class="img_btn fav_off" title="add to fav" />
    </td>
    <td id="des_ali" class="cg_ott">aaaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td id="fav_ali" data-fav_ico="1">
      <img src="img/tmp.png" class="img_btn fav_on" title="del from fav" />
    </td>
    <td id="des_ali" class="cg_na">aaaaa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I use the solution with $(".img_btn#btn_fav_on_off").click(function () {.. because this table is in a complex dialog which is loaded by a parent page..

Comment: oops! .. New problem .. if I dynamically add a new line, the click on the new row images is not working. :( You know how to help me

Comment: I'd start a new question for that. It sounds like you need a delegated event handler, although my example above is using one

Comment: if I use $(document).on('click', '.fav_off, .fav_on', function() { it work but if I use $(".img_btn#btn_nuovo_utente").click(function () { it does not work.

Comment: I can not use the document because loading the page in a dialog and I wish it were independent of the parent page

Comment: The fact your UI is in a dialog makes no difference, you just need to amend the selector of the delegated event handler, like this: `$(document).on('click', '.img_btn#btn_nuovo_utente', function() {`. If that still doesn't work, please start a new question with an example of your current code

Answer (score 0):

you could do this

```
$('.img_btn').on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //change DB...
  console.log(this.id);
  if (this.id == "fav_on") {
    this.id = "fav_off";
  } else {
    this.id = "fav_on";
  }
});
```